# Reset MySQL root password to "default" - MAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, terminal, mamp

I changed my root level password on phpMyAdmin. I was unsure where to enter the password itself, as it did not give me the option (login form). I wondered if it was the php.ini file but users with read privileges  could read it if I placed the password in there.

Now, the mysql doesn't run as I tried various online resources to fix the problem. If needs be I would delete mamp and re-install but I do not want to lose my database files. Ideally I would revert the password to default, which I believe was nothing, except now I cannot connect to phpmyadmin, or the mamp start page:

```
Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!
```

Any help would be great.

UPDATE -

Error message from mamp:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seemed to have fixed it when using terminal to reset the password:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password newpassword
```

Found on [mamp faq](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q9).

Comment: No this won't work. You need 'password' to do this---and the person who asked the question lacks this!

Answer (score 1):

Look in the files:

- checkMysql.sh
- quickCheckMysqlUpgrade.sh
- repairMysql.sh
- stopMysql.sh

The important one in this case is "quickCheckMysqlUpgrade.sh".
All the files are located in the **/Applications/MAMP/bin/** directory.

In these files you'll find something like

```
# /bin/sh
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck --quick --check-upgrade -u root -proot --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql
```

When you see **-proot** that is the password MAMP will try to use,
-p{password}.

-p means "password" and whatever comes after is the password.
So change "-proot" to eg. "-pmysecret" or whatever your password is.

Answer (score 0):

I was being annoyed by the startup "access denied" error MAMP would show, even though I was able to access my site using phpMyAdmin or other SQL tools.  I even found/updated the password in checkMysql.sh, repairMysql.sh,  and upgradeMysql.sh.  I did not notice the script called quickCheckMysqlUpgrade.sh and correcting the password in that fixed the startup error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue on my MBP!
In MAMP Pro (v352), go to the MySQL tab and press "Change Password".

Comment: Does MAMP Pro have its own files, or does canging the password in the GUI edit the files one normally has to change manually in the free version of MAMP?