# MAMP lost access to database, error #1045

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using MAMP and had set up a database through phpMyAdmin locally for a Wordpress install.

It has been fine, and then today I tried to access phpMyAdmin and get:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected 
 the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your 
 configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given
 by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I haven't changed or touched anything to my knowledge, just been working on my Wordpress site.

What can I do? I googled a lot to try and find a solution but none of it made sense with what I have in front of me. How can I change a password when I can't access anything?

I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Did it automatically update the version? Have you checked the ports are the same as they used to be?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018201/reset-mysql-root-password-to-default-mamp

Comment: @brasofilio I tried changing the password through terminal. now what? I still get the error.

Comment: This is what I get when I use terminal to reset the password: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this, just doing some google-fu. Here's another interesting q&a: http://superuser.com/questions/784992/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no

Comment: Just restart db server with --skip-grant-tables and set the password.

Comment: some dumb questions that might turn things around: is your user allowed to connect from localhost? you can check this using terminal. Is the databse on your localhost?